# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop hangs randomly

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I have 16.04 (64 bit) running in a virtualbox VM (using VBox 5.1.8 now, but it happened with previous versions of VBox too). The only application I'm running when Ubuntu hangs is Firefox. I use Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) on the same host machine without issue, but I'd like to use 16.04 if at all possible (if I can get it stable enough). I never run the two VMs at the same time.

Making a wild guess in the dark I think it's graphics related - the laptop I run the VMs on has 'Intel(R) HD 4000 graphics'.

Both the 14.04 and 16.04 VMs have 2GB of RAM (on an 8GB host) and (oddly) I've given them both 3 cores (on a quad core 64bit host: i7-3630QM). I could have given them both 4 cores and still been within the 'green' limit as indicated by Virtualbox. I've installed the VBox guest additions.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but if anyone could suggest where to investigate it would be appreciated.

Comment: How much RAM have you given it? How many CPU cores did you give it? Did you install the VBox graphics drivers?

Comment: I've given both the 14.04 and 16.04 VMs 2GB of RAM (on an 8GB host) and (oddly) I've given them both 3 cores. I could give them both 4 cores and still be within the 'green' limit as indicated by Virtualbox. I've installed the VBox guest additions - is that where the VBox graphics driver is?

Comment: Please click the option highlighted in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffmBv.png, and then install the drivers on the virtual CD in the VM. If that's the solution, I'll post it as an answer that you can accept :)

Comment: Yes, those are the guest additions I've installed (by running sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run). Unfortunately it does occur with those installed.

Comment: What CPU do you have in the host?

Comment: The host CPU is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM, (Quad core - 64 bit).

Comment: And what OS do you have on the host?

Comment: The host is running Windows 10 (64 bit)

Comment: Can you try using Lubuntu and see if it hangs?

Comment: It would take a while to set it up with the same firefox addons and other settings. If Lubuntu 16.04 works fine would it help to pin-point where the problem is with my Ubuntu 16.04? Or do you mean that if Lubuntu works I'd be better off using that instead of Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: *"If Lubuntu 16.04 works fine would it help to pin-point where the problem is with my Ubuntu 16.04?"* - **Exactly :)**